# How to pull Array from tableview to detail view?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parsing, uitableview, segue

I am using a dictionary to populate tableview with objects. table view cells are set to subtitle, two arrays in this dictionary are used to display data for tableview (title and sub). Now I'm interested how to send the rest of arrays in this dictionary to the next "detail view". I am using Parse to store this dictionary data. I simply need to show 3 more fields from the same database on my details when cell is activated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to show the rest of the data of the other arrays in your `detail view`.

Use the `delegate method` of the table view "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`". Here allocate the controller you want use as `Detail View` in your `Controller`, assign to this `Detail Controller` the info you got taking the index of the cell touched, and make a push to this Detail View.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   DetailController *detailVC=[[UIControllerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailController" bundle:nil];

   detailVC.textFieldOne.text=[self.arrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   detailVC.textFieldTwo.text=[self.arrayTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   detailVC.textFieldThree.text=[self.arrayThree objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you have time to look at it this is the full thread I've been beating my head on this all day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544672/parse-array-data-not-being-read-in-detail-view

Comment: I just tried you method above and it says incompatible pointer types initialising "detail view" with expression of type "tableview"controller

Answer (score 0):

I seen you are using Storyboards.

Try to asign with `Key-Value-Coding` the value on `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass: [BookDetailViewController class]]) {
        BookDetailViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFile:");

    if ([destination respondsToSelector:selector]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.bookstableview indexPathForCell:sender];

            PFObject * object = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"BooksTableView"];

            [destination setValue:file forKey:@"file"];
        }


    }
}
```

And try to delete the call to `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` before you perform the segue on your didSelectRow. If you don't want show the row selected, you can edit that on the Attributes Inspector disabling `"Show selection on touch"` of your `Table View` in your Storyboard view.

Comment: Doesn't seem to accept the "setValue:selection". Says undeclared selector, also i added a breakpoint right after the "didselectrow" function and it doesn't seem to call prepare for segue at all. I deleted the selector part and replaced it with [[segue destinationViewController] setFile:file]; app runs fine except when i click on the tableview cells it doesn't initiate the segue.

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer, I was asigning to the key @"file" a wrong value, is not selection, is the file object. So use setValue:file

Comment: Yep, i got rid of the segue identifier now it pushes the segue, the information its supposed to display doesn't show in label or in image. but it does show it reads in debugger

Comment: then try to pass the PFObject, instead of the PFFile, that I guess belongs to your image. And you get with the related key the object you want display.

Comment: Still no luck, ill try again tomorrow. Thanks for your help man. I spent all day on this trying to get a few strings and an image across haha…

Answer (score 0):

To show the image from a `PFObject`:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"nameOfParseClass"];

NSArray *objectsPFFounded=[NSArray arrayWithArray:[query findObjects]];

int i=0;
        while (i<count){
            PFFile *ImageFile = [objectsPFFounded objectAtIndex:i][@"nameOfImageObjectKey"];
            [ImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {

                   //HERE YOU GOT THE IMAGE
                   UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]

                }
            }];
            i++;
        }
```